# Undefined reference to shared library functions after converting from C to C++

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, mex

I have a shared library `libsharedlib.so' which used to be generated from C files. Since the library now needs to use functions from a 3rd party C++ library, I would like to convert my shared library from C to C++ (the code is relatively simple). Based on the differences I read [here](http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/cppcen.html), the only adaptations I had to do were in my use of stdlib and stdio functions. The headers were changed from

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
```

To

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

And all calls to the functions in these libraries are prefixed with the `std::` namespace (e.g. `std::malloc` instead of `malloc`, I did not use `using namespace std`). The source file extensions were changed from .c to .cpp. I also had to add newlines at the end of each file, and had to cast my `malloc`'s. No other compiler feedback after that. The shared library is compiled with the following command:

```
pgcpp -shared -I./inc/ -o ./lib/libsharedlib.so file1.cpp file2.cpp ...
```

And returns no errors or warnings.

I now have a MEX function, `mex_gateway.cpp` which calls functions from this library:

```
#include "sharedlibraryheader.h"
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
             int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){
...
function_from_library(data);
}
```

It is compiled with the following command

```
mex -L./lib/ -lsharedlib -I./inc/ mex_gateway.cpp
```

Which (when adding the verbose flag `-v`) actually executes the following commands:

```
g++ -c  -I./inc/ -I/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include -I/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "mex_gateway.cpp"

g++ -O -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined -o  "mex_gateway.mexa64"  mex_gateway.o  -L./lib/ -lsharedlib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64 -L/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
```

I get the following error:

```
mex_gateway.o: In function `mexFunction':
mex_gateway.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `function_from_library(...arguments...)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "mex_gateway.mexa64"' failed.
```

Of course, I triple-checked the build commands which have the right path to the shared library and the library name. The shared library does have the definition of the function:

```
[user@machine]$ nm lib/libsharedlib.so | grep function_from_library
000000000000198a t __function_from_library__FPCdN51dN27iiiiPdPdPdPdPdPdEND
0000000000001360 T function_from_library__FPCdN51dN27iiiiPdPdPdPdPdPd
```

So where's the problem?

EDIT: My `sharedlibraryheader.h` file looks like this:

```
#ifndef __SHAREDLIBRARYHEADER_H__
#define __SHAREDLIBRARYHEADER_H__

#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

int function1 ( ... );
...
void function_from_library( ... );
...

#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: If it were me, I would probably just leave everything in C, if it works.

Comment: That isn't an option, as I have to call functions from a C++ library.

Comment: It might be easier to write a shim, re-exporting C++ functions as C functions.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do something like:

```
extern "C" {
#include "sharedlibraryheader.h"
}
```

This will let the compiler know that the functions defined in `sharedlibraryheader.h` conform to the C ABI instead of the C++ ABI.  Normally, this is handled in the header itself, in the following manner:

```
// Typically put headers outside extern "C"
#include "..."
#include "..."

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

... rest of header here ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

You have to do this both for the code that uses the shared library **AND** the shared library itself, when compiling it.

Comment: Yes, this does sound like a problem with name mangling causing the C++ compiler to generate/expect decorated function names while the C one is using plain names.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already did that! But why whould the SO be treated as a C library when it is compiled from CPP files?

Comment: @lodhb If you already did that, then you need to edit your question to include that information.  The main reason why a linker can't find a C function called by a C++ app is the name-mangling/extern "C" issue.

Comment: @lodhb: Because the library itself is actually compiled from C files! But now you're recompiling its headers (as part of _your_ project) as C++, and suddenly the definitions do not match the declarations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, I just modified my question!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How can this be, when all files are `.cpp` and are compiled by a C++ compiler (PGCPP)?

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that if there is no C++ code in the .cpp files that you are trying to compile, that you can actually compile them as C source (with GCC) and linking that into your C++ project? In makefiles that I regularly create I will do something like:

```
GPPWALL = g++ -Wall -c
GCCWALL = gcc -Wall -c

...

all: glxgraphics.o shadermanager.o sdlkeyboard.o sdlmouse.o main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp LevelGenerator.cpp $(ASSETSOURCE) $(GRAPHICSSOURCE) $(IOSOURCE) $(BASE)AudioManager.cpp -o avgame $(GLUTLIBS) $(GRAPHICSLIBS) $(PTHREADLIBS) $(OPENALLIBS)

...

sdlmouse.o: $(BASE)avg_mouse.c $(BASE)avg_mouse.h
    $(GCCWALL) $(BASE)avg_mouse.c $(GLUTLIBS)
```

Notice that I have linked the C compiled code into the C++ to avoid the 'extern C' guards which are still ultimately C++ code? This is common practice.